# CodedUi data driven test from configuration file could not load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework

Tags: c#, .net, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to set up my CodedUi project to iterate through an excel file, but want the connection string to be stored in my app.config file. I found a helpful MSDN walkthrough (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243192.aspx), but when I ran my test, I got this exception:

Result Message: 
Unit Test Adapter threw exception: 
The type initializer for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestConfiguration' threw an exception.
An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for microsoft.visualstudio.testtools: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. ([filepath])

Configuration values at present:

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: I changed the "Version" value to "10.0.0.0" and it worked. Hope this helps!

Comment: Because I couldn't find the answer online. I want to help out the next person who runs into this issue